# Install node.js and mongoDB on Cubietruck

Tags: linux, node.js, mongodb

I have installed [Cubian](http://cubian.org/downloads/) OS on my [Cubieboard](http://docs.cubieboard.org/tutorials/cubietruck/start).
Then I installed node.js and mongoDB using this [tutorial](http://c-mobberley.com/wordpress/2013/10/14/raspberry-pi-mongodb-installation-the-working-guide/).
It seems node.js is working properly. I can start mongod service but I have several problems:

1. I cannot execute mongo shell: command not found
2. localhost:27017 (same as http://127.0.0.1:27017/ is unavailabe)
3. I cannot connect to mongoDB in my node.js code
4. `npm install` produce a lots of errors and I can't install required modules using this command (but I still can use `nmp install module_name` command)

My test node.js code:

```
var express = require('express');

// Mongoose import
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error);
db.once('open', function() {
  // Create your schemas and models here.
    console.log('Connected');
});


// Mongoose connection to MongoDB (ted/ted is readonly)
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});

// Mongoose Schema definition
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    email: String
});

// Mongoose Model definition
var User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

// Bootstrap express
var app = express();

// URLS management

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send("<a href='/users'>Show Users</a>");
});

app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
    User.find({}, function (err, docs) {
        res.json(docs);
    });
});

app.get('/users/:email', function (req, res) {
    if (req.params.email) {
        User.find({ email: req.params.email }, function (err, docs) {
            res.json(docs);
        });
    }
});

// Start the server
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

});
```

When I execute `sudo node server.js` command I get following:

```
 Example app listening at http://0.0.0.0:3000
[Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]]
```

As you can see the IP address is incorrect and localhost:3000 (127.0.0.1:3000) is unavailable too.

Does anyone can help me? 
Thanks!

Comment: Despite the code presented this would seem to indicate that your installation of MongoDB was not a success if the build target executables do not exist. At the very least they are not in the path and there is no evidence to support you have a running `mongod` process. So this really isn't a programming question and as such is off topic for here.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following lines to /etc/network/interfaces and after that my web-site became available:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```